# how to resize image in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I trying to resize the image uploaded by user without cropping it.
For that I am using following code.

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['new_image']    = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 75;
    $config['height']   = 50;
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $config['new_image']    = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['width']     = 1000;
    $config['height']   = 400;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

but the problem is that it does not give me the image size 1000x400. it gives me the image with size 534x400. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: You can accept the answer in case it works for you...so everyone can rely on this answer

Comment: You are right Mr. Sharma. Thanx

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please mark it checked so that everyone can see it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` to $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 2):

Change this property to

> $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;